# Counting the percentage of times that the values in two separate columns are not equal for a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataset with 5 columns:

```
0   1   2   3   4
A   Y   N   N   Y
B   N   Y   N   N
C   N   N   N   N
D   Y   Y   N   Y
E   N   Y   Y   Y
F   Y   Y   N   Y
G   Y   N   N   Y
```

I want to calculate the percentage of times that in columns 3 and 4 combined Y appears, and the percentage of time N appears in those two columns combined.

I know how to do it individually using

```
df['3'].value_counts(normalize=True) * 100
```

But can't figure out how to do it with 3 and 4 combined.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the `value_counts` for both columns 3 and 4 by melting them together:

```
df[['3','4']].melt().value.value_counts(normalize=True) * 100
```

Output:

```
N    57.142857
Y    42.857143
Name: value, dtype: float64
```

This gives you the number of times `Y` and `N` appear in either column 3 or 4, as a percentage of the total number of entries in both columns. If you instead want the count of times `N` or `Y` appear in both columns, you could concatenate the strings in each column and then count the combinations:

```
(df['3'] + df['4']).value_counts(normalize=True) * 100
```

Output:

```
NY    57.142857
NN    28.571429
YY    14.285714
dtype: float64
```

## Testing it out

Here's the complete code I used to generate the outputs in the answer above:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

d = '''0   1   2   3   4
A   Y   N   N   Y
B   N   Y   N   N
C   N   N   N   N
D   Y   Y   N   Y
E   N   Y   Y   Y
F   Y   Y   N   Y
G   Y   N   N   Y'''

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(d), sep='\s+')

totalcount = df[['3','4']].melt().value.value_counts(normalize=True) * 100
print('percentage of times each value appears as an entry in either column\n%s\n' % totalcount)

paircount = (df['3'] + df['4']).value_counts(normalize=True) * 100
print('percentage of times each pair of values occurs across columns\n%s\n' % paircount)
```

Comment: +1 for getting the right answer with `(df['3'] + df['4']).value_counts(normalize=True)`, and I wish I could give another +1 for demonstrating how to turn text to a DataFrame with `pd.read_csv(StringIO(d), sep='\s+')`.

Comment: Yeah, it seems like a lot of question askers give their example dataframes as the output of `print(df)` without realizing how annoying it is to load that output into test code. I'm glad I finally came up with a good alternative to manual entry.

Comment: @user1717828 Also, did you mean to +1 the answer in the comments without upvoting it?

Comment: Hahah!  Thanks!  I got so excited about using that on other questions I must have forgotten to actually upvote it.  Agree with your point by the way.  I have been pasting into a text file and replacing consecutive spaces with ` ` in vim, then importing with `load_csv`.  This is much faster.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
print((df['3']+df['4'])[~(df['3']+df['4']).isin(['NY','YN'])].value_counts(normalize=True)*100)
```

Output:

```
NN    66.666667
YY    33.333333
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0):

To count where Y exists in both columns 3 and 4

```
((df['3']=='Y') & (df['4']=='Y')).value_counts(normalize=True) * 100
```

To count where N exists in both columns 3 and 4

```
((df['3']=='N') & (df['4']=='N')).value_counts(normalize=True) * 100
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was looking for something slightly different but I edited the code you gave to give this:    ((df['home_conference'])==(df['away_conference'])).value_counts(normalize=True) * 100

Answer (score 0):

Using `melt`

```
df[['3','4']].melt().value.value_counts(normalize=True)
Out[8]: 
N    0.571429
Y    0.428571
Name: value, dtype: float64
```